# How to manage association in many to many with extra column without getting EntityAlreadyExist Exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have many to many with extra column (activated) in spring jpa and i want to edit the association (add/remove different links).

```
class Question
.....

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
private Set<OutletQuestion> outletQuestions = new HashSet<>();
.....

class Outlet
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "outlet", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
private Set<OutletQuestion> outletQuestions = new HashSet<>();
......

@Entity
@Table(name = "outlets_questions")
public class OutletQuestion implements Serializable {


@Id
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "outlet_id")
private Outlet outlet;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
private Question question;

@Column(name="activated")
private boolean activated;

public Outlet getOutlet() {
    return outlet;
}

public void setOutlet(Outlet outlet) {
    this.outlet = outlet;
}

public Question getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(Question question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public boolean isActivated() {
    return activated;
}

public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
    this.activated = activated;
}
```

}

My Code for editing the links between the Outlet and the Question:

```
   public Question saveWithOutlets(QuestionWithOutletsRequest questionWithOutletsRequest) {
        Question question = questionRepository.findOne(questionWithOutletsRequest.getQuestionId());

        List<Outlet> outletsToLink = outletRepository.findAll(questionWithOutletsRequest.getOutletIds());

// remove all previous links   
 question.getOutletQuestions().removeAll(question.getOutletQuestions());
// insert new
        for (Outlet o : outletsToLink) {
            OutletQuestion oq = new OutletQuestion();
            oq.setActivated(true);
            oq.setOutlet(o);
            oq.setQuestion(question);
            question.getOutletQuestions().add(oq);
        }

        questionRepository.save(question);
        return question;
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [tipps.core.domain.OutletQuestion#tipps.core.domain.OutletQuestion@7d5800b5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID of OutletQuestion is the join between Outlet and Question. The moment you call `questionRepository.save(question);` all the old OutletQuestion in the database haven't been deleted yet. You only removed them from the Set (`question.getOutletQuestions().removeAll(question.getOutletQuestions());`) , but not from the database.

If you try to add the same OutletQuestion again, you will get the EntityExistsException. Try removing all OutletQuestions from the database before adding the new ones.

Comment: I tried adding saveAndFlush after the removeAll():
        question.getOutletQuestions().removeAll(question.getOutletQuestions());
        questionRepository.saveAndFlush(question);

No luck, still same exception.

Comment: You have to remove them acively with a OutletQuestionRepository. The Cascading wont work here.

Comment: What should the PK of this OutletQuestionRepository be?

Comment: Cascading doesn't work with shared primary keys. You have to write the Query yourself. 'delete from OutletQuestion where outlet_id = ?1' or something like that.